# Jquery problem, I want to return back height of my css

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've made a script but i have some problems.
I want that my div `"#potentialCUmsg"` to have `height:300px` when reading message, and then turn back to `height:500px` when the close button is pressed. First part by resizing to height 300px works, but the then does't turn back to 500px:

When reading message:

```
function showOneContactUsMsg(id){
    var msgid = id;
    var showMsg = $.post("process/db/showCUMsg.php", {msgid: msgid});
    showMsg.done(function(data){
        $("#potentialCUmsg").css("height","300px");
        $("#ucp-show-msg").css("display","block");
        $("#ucp-show-msg").html(data);
    });
}
```

When close button is pressed:

```
function closeCUMsgWindow(){
    $("#potentialCUmsg").css("height","500px");
    $("#ucp-show-msg").css("display","none");
}
```

Comment: Could you put this code into a snippet?

Comment: sorry, i can't it's with ajax

Comment: Just leave the ajax part out and replace the `.done` with a button press.

Comment: I see that in snippet works

Comment: "Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See How to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example."